# DNS gone after wakeup

Tags: macbook-pro, dns

I'm having problems with the DNS resolution after a wakeup from sleep.
The system I'm running is Mac OS X Lion 10.7, and I am properly connected to my Wifi.

When I issue a `ping google.com` in the Terminal, it just works. But going through any browser or Application that requires internet access, they all can't resolve the hostname.

I can solve this issue by going to System Preferences > Network Settings and I deactive/activate my Wifi. After that everything works again.

Where else can I look into to solve this permanently?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem. I'm starting to think that this is a virus of some sort, but am unable to find anything conclusive. I've "favorited" this question. Hopefully someone will chime in with something useful soon!  Very oddly it's specific to google.com.  I'm not on Lion, I'm still on 10.6, so, it's not an OS specific issue.

Comment: I am having similar issues - endless "Looking for ..." messages in the browser's statusbar. I have had this with both my old an my new macbook pro. But only on my home WiFi network. So I assume there is some combination of OS X + my internet provider's configuration that is causing this.

Comment: So far: I am now running on a newer version of Mac OSX (10.10.2, Yosemite) and I have not seen this problem ever since.

Comment: This question is a bit older than the other. I still Wireshark installed and the problem does not appear.

Comment: I have had the same problems for several years now, even with Yosemite, both wired and wireless, on two machines. Somehow the DNS seems to go haywire. I can ping the DNS server by IP nummer without problems. But name resolution fails. Killing the discoveryd service does not make a difference.

Comment: I turned off all of the firewall settings of my cable modem (main suspects "IPv6 Firewall Protection" and "IP Flood Detection"). And now things seem to work fine.