# DNS resolution temporarily failing

Tags: macos, network, dns

Macbook air mid-2012 w/ Mountain Lion.

Whenever I wakeup from a long sleep and also on some random moments when it's on, i get DNS resolution failures for every server, with nslookup saying `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`; however, direct connections to IP addresses work correctly, since (among others) Skype works perfectly.

This resolves by itself after more or less 5 minutes, when DNS resolution gets back to work correctly, both with nslookup and in other applications (browser etc.).

I have Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) configured both on my network preferences and on my wireless router's settings.

Possibly related but still unsolved: [DNS gone after wakeup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19908/dns-gone-after-wakeup)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try monitoring the DNS in your Console?

Comment: It may also be worth noting that EVERY device on my home network (Android phones, pcs and PS3) seems to be failing DNS lookups when these temporary failures occur.